# How to decrease c compilation time in a huge project when a small core code changes

Tags: c

The question comes from an interview. The interviewer asks me how to improve the c code compile time in their huge project if they only change part of the project. The question is not about how to use gcc option, it is about how to resolve the dependence in a huge project.

Comment: Combine multiple c files into one big c file. Each time one c file change, move it to its own file. Therefore, files you do not change often are compiled once. Others are compiled when you change them.

Comment: I don't know if it's an option, but I'd say break the project down into libraries so you only need to compile the library that's modified.

Comment: I'd go with using CMAKE. It's protable, easy to maintain, automates parallelization, and the dependencies are resolved for you so only re linking is required. If some chunk of code changes frequently, isolating it in static library and deciding on a public interface will warn the programmers  that changing the interface will probably require recompiling a big part of the project. [SCU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_Compilation_Unit) will reduce the linking time, but requires knowing what you're doing.

Comment: Use of dynamic libraries can cut down on linking time as the whole project won't need to be re-linked because of a small change in another part of the project.

Comment: This article is about [Auto Dependency Generation](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/) using GNU Make. I would suggest you read the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) and this article for some good information on this topic

Comment: What are you allowed to do with the project? Rewrite from scratch? Using awesome tools? Just tiny hacks? Is the interviewer a moron who just nods to whatever you say if you say it with confidence? Or is he/she a fellow hacker?

Comment: We can't possibly answer this without more information, most importantly what build system they are currently using. If they are rebuilding *everything* every time any change is made then the answer that suggests using 'make' is a good one, but I would tend to automatically assume that any project more than a single file is using Make/CMake or similar already unless the original programmer was completely incompetent...

Answer (score 0):

The best method to speed up the compilation is to use the `make` utility